# What is a good way to stop a subscription to a Rabbit MQ queue without notifying the server?

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp, bunny

Using the Bunny gem to subscribe:

```
session = Bunny.new
session.start
channel = session.create_channel
queue   = channel.queue( queue_id, { durable: true })

queue.subscribe do | delivery_info, metadata, payload |
  puts payload
end
```

How can I unsubscribe without letting the server know?

Use case: When a consumer drops off the network, the server is not notified. So I need to find a way of handling this issue. But when the script exits or the thread is killed, it apparently cleans up and notifies the server.

Comment: I don't understand your question because a server must be aware of dead consumer or unsubscribed consumer. You may have a look at the [hearthbeat feature](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html)

Comment: We are having an issue with lost messages when the network connection drops and I am trying to simulate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running under linux your test could execute the iptables command to block connection to RabbitMQ. For example:

```
iptables -i lo -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5672 -j DROP
```

To remove the DROP rule, you can execute:

```
iptables -D INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5672 -j DROP
```

Comment: Yes, after playing with Wireshark I had the same idea. I was wondering which unix command to use, as there seems to be many ways to manage ports.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to unplug your network cable, or disable your wifi card?

if that isn't an option, i would suggest finding a tool that will simulate this effect for you. but really, i think having a hard wired connection and then unplugging the physical cable would be the best way to reproduce the situation on demand.

Comment: Yes, unplugging the cable is an effective method. However, it is a very poor way of testing and development. So I am looking for a way of simulating that via code. Also, I want the Rabbit MQ instance running on the same machine, so unplugging would not work in that case.